# В MySql Workbench отсутствует файл mysql.data.dll

Tags: windows-10, mysql-workbench

В MySql Workbench 8.0.19.0 отсутствует файл mysql.data.dll. Переустанавливал MySql, так и не появился . Если скачивать его, то какой версии. Если он под другим именем, то под каким? Покажите пж скрин папки с mysql.data.dll. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он должен быть?

Comment: Хорошо, тогда на что мне давать ссылку для подключения бд в windows form?

Comment: Что такое windows form и какое отношение к нему имеет workbench?

Comment: Windows form одно из вариантов создания проекта в Microsoft Visual Studio. Чтобы подключить БД из программы "Mysql Workbench" мне нужно сначала добавить  директиву "using MySql.Data.MySqlClient" (без подключенной ссылки на mysql.data.dll она не работает)

Comment: Ну, если почитать какие-нибудь туториалы про MySQL в C#, то в них написано, что нужно скачать и установить [MySQL Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), а workbench здесь вообще абсолютно ни при чём